# htaccess mirror root in (virtual) subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, dns

First of all: I did look at previous answers on SO but nobody seems to have asked what I need!

My website has a root folder that must continue to work normally.

BUT I need to redirect requests made to a SUBfolder www.domain.com/subfolder/ into the ROOT folder www.domain.com

recap:

> browser requests ROOT folder                               ---> gets ROOT folder [like any normal website]
>
> EXAMPLE: www.domain.com/                        PULLS ---> www.domain.com/
>
> browser requests SUBfolder                                     ---> gets ROOT folder [by htaccess]
>
> EXAMPLE: www.domain.com/subfolder/         PULLS ---->www.domain.com/

Which means that the root folder should continue to work normally and there must be a sort of mirroring of the root folder in a given subfolder.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the use for this, but okay.

```
RewriteRule ^SUBfolder/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

**Edit:** To add the mobile_version get-parameter, as asked for in the comments use:

```
RewriteRule ^SUBfolder/(.*)$ /$1?mobile_version=true [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am dealing with an app that must be loaded into an iframe. The hosting platform requires the mobile version to be in a distinct folder from the normal version. Here is why I need to fool them! I will test it and let you know the outcome shortly. Ps: If I manage to use this code, I always need to append a variable $mobile_version=true to any redirection url. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you need to add it to the querystring? What do you mean with 'redirection url'? (PS be careful about duplicated content if you care about google ranking for this app)

Comment: example: user goes to www.domain.com/mobile --> htaccess should redirect to www.domain.com/mobile/?mobile_version=true . another example: www.domain.com/mobile/fakepage.php --> htaccess should give www.domain.com/fakepage.php?mobile_version=true. So I am trying to always append a php variable to any redirected url!

Comment: So the variable if for the php script, so it knows it has to serve the mobile version. I'll add the solution for that to my original answer.

Comment: ok I tried to use it but it gives me: "Forbidden. You don't have permission to access /SUBfolder_name/ on this server." Maybe the htaccess code you posted in your answer was only part of the complete code required? I tried to enter rewrite engine on plus your code, but I guess I still need a rewrite condition?!

Comment: Add a `RewriteBase /` or change `/$1...` to just `$1...`

Comment: Maybe someone can help me on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942849/mirror-domain-configuration-with-htaccess :)