# Mirror domain configuration with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to make few mirror domains for `example.com`?

Users should be browsing in `example.ru/*` or `example.de/*` domains, but all requests should be sent to `example.com/*` (without redirecting)

I will use it to manage different website languages.

`Is it possible?`

Comment: You don't need mod_rewrite, just point all 3 domains to the same host and setup the virtual host so that it serves all 3 domains.

Comment: Thanks Jon! I'm using them in this way right now, but there are problems with emails - I need them to with every domain :) Of course I can give other DNS for MX parameter of these alias domains

Comment: Your apache setup has absolutely nothing to do with getting email to work. You'll need to setup the DNS for each domain correctly and ensure that your MTA is setup to handle email for all of the domains.

Comment: @bradym: If I'm making mirror domains via virtual host, I can not use emails, so I need htaccess

Comment: No. Apache has nothing to do with email. Apache serves websites. If you need to setup emails, you need to setup an MTA. I recommend Exim. See http://www.exim.org/ and http://library.linode.com/email/exim - even if you don't use linode, those guides for setting up exim are very helpful.